# how to assign pointer in a managed array of pointers c++/cli?

Tags: c++-cli

I am new to managed code and i need to pass array of pointers to different structures to windows form using C++/CLI , but it didn`t work !

My problem is in the managed array, how can i correctly access its elements .

The code sequence :

```
array<void*> ^ ptr;//here ptr value is undefined , type array<void*> ^
ptr = gcnew array<void*> (2);// length 0x2 , 0x0 and 0x1 values are undefined of type void

class1::struct1 structObj1;
class2::struct2 structObj2;

ptr[0] = &structObj1;// value is empty of type void!!
ptr[1] = &structObj2;//value is empty of type void!!
```

When i watched ptr , i found the above comments.

Notice that repeating code but using unmanaged array works probably

```
void* ptr[2];//here ptr value is undefined , type void*[]

class1::struct1 structObj1;
class2::struct2 structObj2;

ptr[0] = &structObj1;// value is address1 of type void*
ptr[1] = &structObj2;//value is address2 of type void*
```

Can anyone see where is the problem??

Do I need to use unmanaged array then convert to managed? If yes, how can I do it ??

Comment: Neither the CLR nor the debugger have much use for a void*.  No type info is available for it.  It is very unclear what type "struct1" might be, you cannot do anything with it in a Winforms app if it is an unmanaged struct.  If it is managed then a way ahead is to use an array of Object^.  Still miserable in the Winforms code but at least it has a shot at it.

Comment: He might be doing a WinForms app in C++/CLI, and need a way to pass unmanaged data from one managed class to another.

Answer (score 2):

Passing unmanaged pointers in a managed array may be valid C++/CLI, but it's definitely not the ideal way to do things. Do consider creating a custom managed class (`ref class` in C++/CLI) to hold the structures, instead of passing around pointers.

For this, I'm assuming that struct1 and struct2 are *unmanged* structs. This answer only applies if that is the case.

Your existing code works for me. Here's my version, with some debugging added in.

```
public struct struct1 { int foo; };
public struct struct2 { float bar; };

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    array<void*> ^ ptr;
    ptr = gcnew array<void*> (2);

    for(int i = 0; i < ptr->Length; i++)
        Debug::WriteLine("ptr[{0}] = {1:X8}", i, reinterpret_cast<int>(ptr[i]));

    struct1 structObj1;
    struct2 structObj2;

    ptr[0] = &structObj1;
    ptr[1] = &structObj2;

    for(int i = 0; i < ptr->Length; i++)
        Debug::WriteLine("ptr[{0}] = {1:X8}", i, reinterpret_cast<int>(ptr[i]));

    struct1* pointerToStructObj1 = reinterpret_cast<struct1*>(ptr[0]);

    structObj1.foo = 4;
    Debug::WriteLine("pointerToStructObj1->foo = {0}", pointerToStructObj1->foo);
}
```

Output:

```
ptr[0] = 00000000
ptr[1] = 00000000
ptr[0] = 0013F390
ptr[1] = 0013F394
pointerToStructObj1->foo = 4
```

---

### Edit

To use Debug::WriteLine, add `using namespace System::Diagnostics`.

The debugger doesn't know how to display the contents of a `void*`, so it just displays blank. It does display a null pointer differently, though: null shows up as `<undefined value>`, non-null shows up as just blank.

My philosophy on C++/CLI is: If you're going to write managed code, *write managed code*. Consider replacing your vector with a managed List. If you still need unmanaged objects, I strongly urge you to consider writing a managed class with properly typed pointers, rather than a `void*` array.

To implement such a class, create whatever fields you need, just be sure that they're pointers, not direct. (`vector<foo>*` instead of `vector<foo>`.) Create the objects with `new` in the constructor, and `delete` them in the destructor (which is called on Dispose) & finalizer.

Comment: thanks alot for your reply , it was very helpful , but i`ve some concerns :

Comment: 1- why normal casting don`t work i.e (struct*)(ptr[0])...it says can`t convert from void* to struct* ?!
2- do we need to include certain header to use Debug::WriteLine   as it didn`t work with me !!
3- do you have any idea why using watch tool , I see nothing in ptr value also we can show it`s value on console(I used cout)
- By the way , I used pointer because , my structures are unmanaged and it contains vector so I couldn`t define it`s content in ref class as use it directly , is there a way other than pointer??

Comment: forget about normal casting question (qs 1) as after changing place of code , it works probably .

Comment: @ David : you are right , void* array isn`t good , what about collecting unmanaged vars in unmanaged class without any structs then create ptr to that class as member variable when needed and make new/delete for class in constructor/destructor , isn`t this better than creating *,new,delete to every unmanaged obj in a managed class ??

Comment: @ David : another question , if i`ve 2 classes a and b , then in class a i created member variable * to b , made new b in constructor and delete in destructor , and class a calls class b method passing the previous member variable then in class b to access the member variable of b in member functions of b why can`t i access them directly and i shall access through the passed pointer ??  <br/>Thanks.

Comment: If the point is to pass unmanaged objects through C# code, then I'd favor a managed class to hold your unmanaged objects. However, either way to hold the unmanaged objects should work.

Comment: I don't understand your 'another question'. Please ask a full-fledged new question, and include a code sample.

Comment: @ David : the point is having global variables (containing vectors)so i put it in unmanaged class and created * to it in my main form then pass this pointer to everywhere else need those variables {i made this to avoid global variables} , anyway when i put them in amanaged class ...i can`t create pointer to that class nor take it`s reference  ....!

Comment: @ David : when say that function will take reference to managed class e.g ref class1 , fn(class1& class1ref) ...i got error C3699?!

Comment: @ David : about the 'another question ' , it`s okay , the mentioned problem doesn`t exist anymore without doing anything !